# Passing function as parameter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to pass a function as a parameter but it throws 'Unit cannot be invoked as function. Thanks in advance.

```
uploadImageToParse(imageFile, saveCall1())
uploadImageToParse(imageFile, saveCall2())
uploadImageToParse(imageFile, saveCall3())

private fun uploadImageToParse(file: ParseFile?, saveCall: Unit) {
        saveCall()//Throws an error saying 'Unit cannot be invoked as function'
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Problem is, that you are not passing a function as a parameter to the `uploadImageToParse` method. You are passing the result. Also `uploadImageToParse` method is expecting `safeCall` to be **Unit** parameter not a **function**.

For this to work you have to first declare `uploadImageToParse` to expect a function parameter.

```
fun uploadImageToParse(file: String?, saveCall: () -> Unit) {
    saveCall()
}
```

Then you can pass function parameters to this method.

```
uploadImageToParse(imageFile, {saveCall()})
```

For more information on the topic take a look at [Higher-Order Functions and Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html) in the Kotlin documentation.

Edit: As @marstran pointed out, you can also pass the function as a parameter using [Function Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references).

```
uploadImageToParse(imageFile, ::saveCall)
```

Comment: `{saveCall()}` can be written `::saveCall`.

Comment: How would you use a function with arguments?

Comment: Basicaly the same, except that instead of empty arg list you specify what args it should take. E.g. myFunction: (path: Path) -> Unit. Take a look at this example from the documentation. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types

Answer (score 8):

Accepting a function pointer as a parameter is done like this:

```
private fun uploadImageToParse(file: ParseFile?, saveCall: () -> Unit){
    saveCall.invoke()
}
```

The `()` are the types of the parameters.

The `-> Unit` part is the return type.

Second Example:

```
fun someFunction (a:Int, b:Float) : Double {
    return (a * b).toDouble()
}

fun useFunction (func: (Int, Float) -> Double) {
    println(func.invoke(10, 5.54421))
}
```

For more information, refer to the [Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Answer (score 2):

Using lambda expression, We can pass method as parameters 

Example:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  MyFunction("F KRITTY", { x:Int, y:Int -> x + y })
}

fun MyFunction(name: String , addNumber: (Int , Int) -> Int) {
  println("Parameter 1 Name :" + name)
  val number: Int = addNumber(10,20)
  println("Parameter 2 Add Numbers : " + number)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct. I also saw a question regarding the cases with parameters. In that case you can use the following:

For example, if the accepting function is like the one below:

```
fun uploadImageToParse(file: String?, saveCallParameter: (a:String,b:Int,c:String) -> Unit) {
saveCall(x,y,z) }
```

Then you could write your call like this:

```
uploadImageToParse(saveCallParameter={a,b,c->saveCall(a,b,c)}
```

Here saveCall is the named parameter.